# Does anyone recognize such connectors?

Tags: connector, cables, fan, pins

These are the connectors used to power a 12V fan. I have both male and female ends attached.
Does anyone know the name of it? I'd like to purchase a extension cable.
It has 8 pins because there are two fan blades. here is its datasheet: https://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/GFC0412DS-SM06B0G.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Measure the pitch. It looks like Molex Picoblade, or any other equivalent 1.25mm pitch connectors.

Comment: Could be a JST connector

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Picoblade except for the mounting tabs - could be a clone - but without knowing the pitch I can't say for sure.  Picoblade is a wire-to-board connector; there are no free hanging male pin headers.  Your options to make an extension cable are to:

1. Buy a through-hole male pin header (the socket), a matching housing (the plug), and pre-crimped jumper wires (I assume you don't want to drop $600 on a crimper).  Cut off one end of the jumper wires and solder straight to the pins on the header.  Good luck insulating it.
2. Buy a suitable breakout board and solder the header into it, solder the jumper wires into the board.
3. Cut the cable and individually splice each wire.